# Res.write is not working when continuously sending UDP packet

Tags: html, node.js, udp

```
//Sending UDP message to TFTP server
//dgram modeule to create UDP socket
var express= require('express'), fs= require('fs'),path = require('path'),util = require('util'),dgram= require('dgram'),client= dgram.createSocket('udp4'),bodyParser = require('body-parser'),app = express(), ejs = require('ejs');
var plotly = require('plotly')("Patidar", "ku0sisuxfm")


// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static('public'));

//Reading in the html file for input page
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index2.html');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});

//reading in html file for output page
app.get('/output', function(req, res){
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index4.html');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});

//Recieving UDP message

app.post('/output', function(req, res){
var once= req.body.submit;

if (once == "Once") {
//Define the host and port values of UDP
var HOST= req.body.ip;
var PORT= req.body.port;
//Reading in the user's command, converting to hex
var message = new Buffer(req.body.number, 'hex');

//Sends packets to TFTP

client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function (err, bytes) {
        if (err) throw err;
  });

//Recieving message back and printing it out to webpage
    client.on('message', function (message) {
 fs.readFile('index3.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
      if (err) {
        res.end('error occurred');
        return;
      }
      var temp = message.toString();  //here you assign temp variable with needed value

      var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {temp:temp, host: HOST, port: PORT});  //get redered HTML code
        res.end(renderedHtml);
      //var data = [{x:[req.body.number], y:[temp], type: 'scatter'}];
      //var layout = {fileopt : "overwrite", filename : "simple-node-example"};
      //plotly.plot(data, layout, function (err, msg) {
        //if (err) return console.log(err);
        //console.log(msg);
      //});
    });
  });
}


if (once == "continuous") {
var timesRun = 0;
var requestLoop = setInterval(function(){
  timesRun += 1;
   if(timesRun === 5){
       clearInterval(requestLoop);
   }
//Define the host and port values of UDP
var HOST= req.body.ip;
var PORT= req.body.port;
//Reading in the user's command, converting to hex
var message = new Buffer(req.body.number, 'hex');

//Sends packets to TFTP

client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function (err, bytes) {
        if (err) throw err;
  });

//Recieving message back and printing it out to webpage

client.on('message', function (message) {
  fs.readFile('index3.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
      if (err) {
        res.end('error occurred');
        return;
      }
      var temp = message.toString();  //here you assign temp variable with needed value

      var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {temp:temp, host: HOST, port: PORT});  //get redered HTML code
      res.write(renderedHtml);

      //var data = [{x:[req.body.number], y:[temp], type: 'scatter'}];
      //var layout = {fileopt : "overwrite", filename : "simple-node-example"};

      //plotly.plot(data, layout, function (err, msg) {
        //if (err) return console.log(err);
        //console.log(msg);
      //});
});
});
}, 10000);
}
});



//Setting up listening server
app.listen(3000, "192.168.0.136");
console.log('Listening at 192.168.0.136:3000');
```

I have two button, one button sends the UDP packet once, while a continuous button sends the same UDP packets every 10 seconds. However, when this button is pressed, res.write is repeating the entire output again. Look at the attached pic to see output[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: This code is impossible to read for a bunch of reasons: ridiculously long lines that contain important code, lack of proper code indentation.

Comment: In the future, please post much more readable code here on stack overflow.  Most people won't bother doing a bunch of work to try to make your code readable in order to understand the question - that is your responsibility to write an easy to understand question if you want to maximize the chance of getting good answers quickly

Comment: i am very sorry about that. Thank you so much for still answering the question! very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting your code into an auto-code-formatter to make it readable, I can see that you are doing this:

```
client.on('message', function (message) { ...
```

inside of your `app.post()` handler.  That means that every time your post handler is called, you add yet another `client.on('message', ...)` event handler.  So, after it's called the 2nd time, you have two event handlers, after it's called the 3rd time, you have three and so on.

So, as soon as you have these duplicate, each will get called and you will get duplicate actions applied.

Your choices are to either:

1. Use `.once()` for the event handler so it is automatically removed after it fires.
2. Remove it manually after it fires or when you are done with it.
3. Add it once outside your `app.post()` handler so you never add duplicates.
4. Restructure the way your code works so it doesn't have this type of issue.  For example, you have two different handlers for the same incoming message.  This is a sign of very stateful code which is more complex to write properly.  A better design that isn't stateful in that way would be simpler.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Quick question- since i open the index3.html file after client.on(), the input and output bars are still opening again with the output like the in the picture, any suggestion on fixing this?

Comment: @patidar - Sorry, but I don't understand what problem you're still trying to solve?

Comment: Do you see in the picture above how the output and input navigation bar is also opening again with the output? Is there anyway I can just update the output in the html file, and not print out the navigation bar again

Comment: Is there something other than res.write i can use, i think because I am using res.write, the html file get written again. Is there something i can do that it will just maybe refresh the page itself ?

Comment: @patidar - `res.write()` is an http response.  It's data you're sending the browser in response to a request the browser made.  If you call `res.write()` multiple times on the same request, it is additive (it adds more to the response each time) and the browser is just rendering ALL the content you send it as it is supposed to.  You have the completely wrong model if you're just trying to update the current web page rather than add to it as that is not something you can do from within an http request that has already sent a bunch of content to the browser.  You can't go back and change that.

Comment: @patidar - You don't really explain the overall problem you're trying to solve.  Because of that, we can't really suggest the proper architecture for that problem - all we can do is point out flaws in the code you show.  I'd suggest maybe you should post a new question where you lay out the actual thing you're trying to implement, discuss what you've tried and why it didn't work and then ask what a better architecture would be for that type of problem.

Comment: Will follow through with the suggestion