# clear res.write after the file is written once in node js?

Tags: html, node.js, udp

```
//Sending UDP message to TFTP server
//dgram modeule to create UDP socket
var express= require('express'), fs= require('fs'),path = require('path'),util = require('util'),dgram= require('dgram'),client= dgram.createSocket('udp4'),bodyParser = require('body-parser'),app = express(), ejs = require('ejs');
var plotly = require('plotly')("Patidar2", "9z2dlsvsqn")


// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static('public'));

//Reading in the html file for input page
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index2.html');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});

//reading in html file for output page
app.get('/output', function(req, res){
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index4.html');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});

//Recieving UDP message

app.post('/output', function(req, res){
  var once= req.body.submit;

  if (once == "Once") {
    //Define the host and port values of UDP
    var HOST= req.body.ip;
    var PORT= req.body.port;
    //Reading in the user's command, converting to hex
    var message = new Buffer(req.body.number, 'hex');

    //Sends packets to TFTP

    client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function (err, bytes) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });

      //Recieving message back and printing it out to webpage
    client.on('message', function (message) {
      fs.readFile('index3.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
      if (err) {
        res.end('error occurred');
        return;
      }
      var temp = message.toString();  //here you assign temp variable with needed value

      var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {temp:temp, host: HOST, port: PORT});  //get redered HTML code
        res.end(renderedHtml);
      //var data = [{x:[req.body.number], y:[temp], type: 'scatter'}];
      //var layout = {fileopt : "overwrite", filename : "simple-node-example"};
  /*    plotly.plot(data, layout, function (err, msg) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(msg);
      }); */
    });
  });
}

//Send UDP packet continuously every ten seconds
   if (once == "continuous") {
     var timesRun = 0;
     var requestLoop = setInterval(function(){
     timesRun += 1;
      if(timesRun === 2){
        clearInterval(requestLoop);
      }
//Define the host and port values of UDP
  var HOST= req.body.ip;
  var PORT= req.body.port;
//Reading in the user's command, converting to hex
  var message = new Buffer(req.body.number, 'hex');

//Sends packets to TFTP

  client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function (err, bytes) {
          if (err) throw err;
      });
}, 10000);
//Recieving message back and printing it out to webpage


    client.on('message', function (message) {
      var HOST= req.body.ip;
      var PORT= req.body.port;
        fs.readFile('index3.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
          if (err) {
            res.end('error occurred');
            return;
          }
          var temp = message.toString();  //here you assign temp variable with needed value

          var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {temp:temp, host: HOST, port: PORT});  //get redered HTML code
          res.write(renderedHtml);
      //var data = [{x:[req.body.number], y:[temp], type: 'scatter'}];
      //var layout = {fileopt : "overwrite", filename : "simple-node-example"};

      //plotly.plot(data, layout, function (err, msg) {
        //if (err) return console.log(err);
        //console.log(msg);
      //});
    });
  });
}
});



//Setting up listening server
app.listen(3000, "192.168.0.136");
console.log('Listening at 192.168.0.136:3000');
```

I have created a continuous button that send the same UDP packet every ten seconds using setInterval, however since I am reading in index3.html. That html file is being duplicated each time a message is received. The picture shows you that. I want to be able to just update the output after each packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the server to be able to send future updates to a page (I'm guessing that what the real problem you're trying to solve here is), then http request/response is NOT the right architecture at all.

Instead, you need a form of server-push where the server can send data to the page whenever it wants the the page can receive that data and then insert it into the page how it wants.

The usual mechanism for that these days is a webSocket or a higher level variant of that, socket.io.

In the socket.io scheme, the server sets up a listener for incoming socket.io connections.  Then, any page that wishes to be able to receive updates, makes a socket.io connection to the server and registers listeners for certain messages.  Then, when something of interest happens on the server and it wants to notify one or more connected web pages, the server can send a socket.io message to that web page.  The web page will receive that message and it can then process it however it wants (e.g. update the currently displayed web page with new data).

You can read more about socket.io here: http://socket.io/.

---

The other option besides a webSocket is for your web page to just regularly send an ajax call to your server and your server can return any new data that it has and the client can then process that data (similar to how the webSocket would process data it was sent).  This is referred to as client polling.  It may be slightly simpler to implement, but it is less scalable and often not as responsive because the client has to regularly ask the server if there's anything new and most of the time the server will just response "nothing new yet".

---

In the future, I'd suggest you avoid posting three questions that are very close to the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999287/using-websockets-with-node-js-udp-server), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014742/res-write-is-not-working-when-continuously-sending-udp-packet) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019452/clear-res-write-after-the-file-is-written-once-in-node-js/38019797#38019797).  Questions should be edited to be made clear rather than just posting again.  And, new questions should be significantly different from prior questions.  If you don't get an answer to your question, it is likely because it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I know sockets is the best option but I am just so lost on how to implement the same design using sockets. Like can you implement something like app.post with sockets?

Comment: @patidar - As I've described, you don't implement the same thing - you need a new architecture to get server-side notification. Trying to send notifications from `app.post()` is just a flawed design and will not work.